# Customize Identity server with Blazor web assembly and asp.net core web api

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

I have created a new application with visual studio and .net core 3.1 and the default template comes with the implementation of Identity Server.

When I start the project and try to login I'm redirected to Identity Server login page and I wonder where this page comes from and how to get control over it.

Also, I would like to add the client referrer as a claim during the registration process and I wonder how to do it seems there is no registration implementation in the project but everything comes from Identity Server library.

Comment: can u post ur program.cs or startup where it calls `AddOidcAuthentication`?

Comment: I have no such method call in any startup. I have something like AddIdentityServer